# Laravel Queue - remembering property state?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

If a job failed, it will be pushed back to the Queue. Is there a way to remember the value of property in the job class when processing job again?

For example:

```
class MailJob extends Job
{
    public $tries = 3;

    public $status;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->status = false; // set to false
    }


    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->status = true;
        // Assume job has failed, it went back to the Queue.
        // status should be true when this job start processing again
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd have to write something to the db in order to preserve state and ensure the job references that data in the db.

Comment: @haakym It seem that is only way :(

Comment: the answer by @haakym is right. Because when you out a job in the queue it runs separately from the main php application. So you can do is just log the failed jobs in the db and during the next run by fetching essential info rerun the failed jobs

Comment: I'm agree with @haakym.

Comment: @mchampaneri You should post answer if you wish.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Apply `failed` method and persist the state in db.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back sure... I'll post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to rerun the failed process again on the same moment. you can do something like this.

Here the object is in memory while rerunning the job so data will be available.

I haven't verified it by running it , but hope it will work

```
class MailJob extends Job{
public $tries = 3;
public $status;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->status = false; // set to false
}


/**
 * Execute the job.
 */
public function handle()
{
    $this->status = true;
    // Assume job has failed, it went back to the Queue.
    // status should be true when this job start processing again

    $failed = processFailedisConfirm();

    if $failed == true && $this->tries > -1 {
         $this->tries = $this->tries - 1;
         $this->handel();
    }
}}
```

Example of processFailedisConfirm could be

```
public function processFailedisConfirm(){

     // Core Process to be done in the Job
     $state = (Do Some Api Call); // Here just example, you may send email
                                  // Or can do the core Job Process
                                  // And depending on the Response of the 
                                  // Process return true or false

     // Is Job failed or not ?
     if ( $state == "200" ){
     return false; // Job is not failed
     } else {
     return true; // Job is failed
}
```

Logic of process is failed or not is depened on the operation you are doing. As i am doing an api call if i get response of 200 my process is successfull. 
Otherwise process is failed.
This just example, sucess reponse of different api can be differnt as desigend by api designer.

Comment: You should show example of `processFailedisConfirm() `

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Laravel does not re-serialize the job in its state, prior to it's failure, to be re-queued.

This means, any properties you set outside of the jobs constructor are not restored on the job when it is ran a second time from a `queue:retry`.

You can test this yourself by creating a queued job that sets a property, then throws an exception. On a subsequent attempt, the property is still equal to its default value.

In the example below, running the queue worker via `queue:work` will result in the job being tried twice. On the second try (attempt), the value of `$this->prop` is still `false`, even though it was set to `true` on the first attempt:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class TestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public $prop = false;

    public $tries = 2;

    public function handle(): void
    {
        if ($this->attempts() === 1) {
            $this->prop = true;
        } else {
            dd($this->prop);
        }

        throw new \Exception();
    }
}
```

You will have to utilize caching, or interact with the database to save job state.

If using a Cache, you may utilize the job's ID for a unique cache key for that specific job:

```php
public function handle(): void
{
    // Generate the value (on first run) or retrieve the value (on subsequent runs).
    $value = Cache::rememberForever($this->job->getJobId(), function () {
        return 'some-value'; 
    });

    // Process the job...

    // Remove the value from the cache.
    Cache::forget($this->job->getJobId());
}
```

On subsequent attempts and retries of the job, the cached value will be retrieved, allowing you to retrieve the value of the first run, rather than retrieving it again.